# Passing and getting hyperlinks into a single JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to do is to take several links that may be on a page and send only the link that was clicked on to a PHP script to be parsed.

```
<a href="?something=2&id=100&somethingelse=55" class="link">My First Link</a>
<a href="?something=3&id=400&somethingelse=65" class="link">My Second Link</a>
```

What I would like is to grab the link and have it passed to PHP. Using this code, I am only ever able to get the first link, no matter which link I click on.

I'd rather have one function to send these links into than a function for each and every hyperlink I have in the site. I'm simply trying to condense or consolidate the amount of functions needed that basically do the same thing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  $(".link").click(function() {
  var v1 = $("a.link").attr("href");

//    var v1 = $("a.ajax-link")[2].href;
    var dataString = 'v1='+ v1;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.success == 1){
          alert(data.success);
        }
        else{
          alert(data.success);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to get the event target (`this` in this case):

```
var v1 = $(this).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".link").click(function() {
  var v1 = $("a.link").attr("href");

//    var v1 = $("a.ajax-link")[2].href;
    var dataString = 'v1='+ encodeURIComponent(v1);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_php_page_to_handle_post",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.success == 1){
          alert(data.success);
        }
        else{
          alert(data.success);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir. I was clearly missing `encodeURIComponent` in this but I am still having the same issue with the same hyperlink being sent even though every link is different. How can I get the proper corresponding link that the user clicked to be sent?

Answer (score 0):

Using $(this) in your handler will give you a reference to the clicked link.

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var dataString = 'v1='+ encodeURIComponent(href);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_php_page_to_handle_post",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.success == 1){
          alert(data.success);
        }
        else{
          alert(data.success);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks jrummell. Where would I use encodeURIComponent so that the entire link is passed?

Comment: I updated my answer with `encodeURIComponent()`. I think that's what you're looking for.